# how to add *Required just above the first 2 panel to marked it as required

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

-Using angular bootstrap nav tag component
The user information and education information are required field.so I want to add *Required just above those tab for notifying users.

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Panel1">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 1}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(1)">**User Information**</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 2}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(2)">**Education information**</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 3}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(3)">Employeement information</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div ng-class="{'tab-pane active': activeTab === 1, 'tab-pane' : activeTab !== 1}">abc</div>
    <div ng-class="{'tab-pane active': activeTab === 2, 'tab-pane' : activeTab !== 2}">def</div>
    <div ng-class="{'tab-pane active': activeTab === 3, 'tab-pane' : activeTab !== 3}">ehg </div>
  </div>
        angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller("Panel1", ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.activeTab = 1;

            $scope.setActiveTab = function(tabToSet) {
                $scope.activeTab = tabToSet;
            }
        }]);
  </script>
```

Comment: Is there any relation between the text and the code? What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my code didn't paste properly. Is the any way in css i can hook up [ *required] above first two nav-tabs

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, and why CSS would be the answer. If you want the text "Required" to appear before the text "User Information" in the tab, then add the text "Required" before "User Information" in the HTML.